# Any Graphical Text Editor for Amazon Linux on EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am looking for something like gedit to use with my amazon linux ec2 instance. I am quite a bit of coding and would prefer the graphical environment over using vim. I am coding mainly php and javascript.

I am not using gedit as the package is not found by yum. I know that I can add the repo, etc. But I am hoping for something that is in the standard repos.

I am hoping someone could provide something like the below command with blah being what ever programs I need to install.

```
yum install blah blah blah
```

Comment: Why don't you develop locally and just deploy to the EC2 instance?

Comment: System has been deployed already. I am making edits and updates. That is what I am doing, but I rather avoid all the wasted time of uploading and downloading.

Comment: No, I mean write your code locally and deploy with [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki), [Chef](http://docs.opscode.com/), etc.

Comment: If an update is more than a configuration/quick fix that can be easily handled in vim, it should probably end up in your repository anyway...

Comment: Server is not connected to a repo because of ec2 security settings that are out of my control.

Comment: @djc391: So how do you deploy code to the server in the first place?

Comment: What security settings would keep your server from being connected to a repo and still be useful as any type of server?

Comment: I wrote my code in Notepad++, created a file in vim on server and copied and pasted. I am not saying that is a good process and that I like doing it this way.

Comment: I recommend continuing with that process, sounds solid to me.

Comment: @djc391: I don't even know what to say. What's preventing you from using a sane approach?

Comment: I use EC2 instances all the time and have them synced with both HG and GIT respositories on BitBucket... what security settings are you referring to that are keeping you from using this method?  I have some ideas related to pushing and pulling SFTP files, but I'm assuming they will be similarly blocked.

Comment: Security settings are set to block everything but http, and ssh accsess from my ip.

Comment: @djc391: Why don't you change them? Even with just SSH access, Capistrano can work for you: https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano

Comment: The primary point there "From his IP" so there is no access from any other computer.  Use SFTP put and get commands from your cmputer, or set up filezilla on a folder in your computer(same protocols just pretty graphical interface) to sync with items from that folder to a folder on your EC2 instance.

Comment: I like that Chris, and I figured out how to set it all up to work. But it was a pain because the files that I am editing could only be edited by root. They were in /var/www/html/ but I used symlinks to get around it. Edit your answer to that, its a better reply.

Comment: I would make further fun of you for resorting to this, but the only reason I know that trick is because I use to use it to sync files between my laptop and campus computers in college before I knew what a repository was :)

Comment: I know this has been answered, but I think @DanCiborowski-MSFT ran into same problems as any newcomer to AWS EC2, and for other newcomers I'd say that root will have access initially. We need to override that with chmod on the folders you need write access to. So e.g. if you want to write to the /var/www/html folder, you need to chmod 755 on that folder. Otherwise you would run into permissions problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SFTP put and get commands from your cmputer, or set up filezilla on a folder in your computer(same protocols just pretty graphical interface) to sync with items from that folder to a folder on your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have ssh access to your linux instance on amazon - just use sshfs to mount the remote code directory and use whatever your preferred local poison is.

Not that I think this is a sensible approach; the suggestions in the comments make far more sense.